# How to write long conversation of (whispers) when screenwriting?

Tags: style, formatting, screenwriting

If you have a conversation of whispering in a screenplay do you have to put:

> BATHSHEBA
>   (whispers)

Beneath each character’s name.
I’ll add that the situation mandates whispering and could be understood easily I think.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, the name and any special instructions are printed in the margin beside the spoken lines, which are themselves in a block of text and indented.
I take it that such is what you meant when you said “beneath”.

Use of abbreviations can be done — *e.g.*

> (whis.)

— but should not be necessary unless you are conserving space or substrate *i.e.* paper.

A screenplay is meant to be accurate in conveying information to the director and the performers.  They will use marks and highlighting as necessary to help them learn the lines; but, unless you provide such necessary information in the first place, how will they know it?

If an entire dialogue is done in a certain mode, then you can make such a note prior to the entire sequence.  E.g.

> The dialogue in this scene is done entirely in whispering.

Phrase that however is best.

Answer (score 4):

Use parentheticals to establish that each character is whispering. It should then be implied that they continue in the same mode until one of them speaks up — at which point, you likewise establish that they speak up.

```
                               BATHSHEBA
                         (whispers)
                     How should I introduce you?

                               JOHN
                         (whispers)
                     By my name.

                               BATHSHEBA
                     Right. Makes sense.

                               JOHN
                     Yeah...

                               BATHSHEBA
                         (speaks up)
                     Hey, Larry, this is John.
```

Comment: I hope you don't take my edit to be commandeering your answer; I simply thought that it could stand for some improvement.

Comment: Well, I did misspell “use,” so...